# Push to global array from multiple API requests

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a function that calls a paginated API. It makes an initial call to the first page, then continues to make requests to the subsequent pages using the `next` url returned in the response. It does this until `next` is `null`. I am trying to extract data (city names) from the response and push these to a global array.

My code currently looks like this:

```
var results = [];
function nextPage(url) {
    if (!url) {
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        nextPage(data.next);
        $.each(data.results, function (k, v) {
            results.push(v.city_name);
        });
    });
}

nextPage('http://url.com/api/v1/cities/?page=1');
console.log(results);
```

Assuming I have two pages of JSON that look like this:

*Page 1*

```
{
    "count": 105,
    "next": "http://url.com/api/v1/cities/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "city_name": "Paris"
        },
        {
            "city_name": "Brussels"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Page 2*

```
{
    "count": 105,
    "next": null,
    "previous": "http://url.com/api/v1/cities/?page=1",
    "results": [
        {
            "city_name": "Manchester"
        },
        {
            "city_name": "Curitiba"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect the array to look like this:

```
["Paris", "Brussels", "Manchester", "Curitiba"]
```

However, when I log `results` to the console the array is empty. Can anyone help? Let me know if you need any more information. Cheers

Comment: Looks right. Try console.log()'ing data right before the second call to nextPage(), maybe the response is not what you expect.

Comment: nextPage is asynchronous--console.log is getting called before it manages to retrieve any data and store it in the global results array.

Comment: You are trying to access the `results` array data before the javascript call is finished. Try putting your `console.log()` inside `$.each()`. I am sure you will see that you have your data being entered correctly in the `results` array.

Comment: Agreed, when I put log inside the function it returns data, however it returns two list that accumulates with each loop. Is this the expected behaviour? All I want is one array.

Comment: There are multiple ways to tackle this issue as `$.getJSON()` is async. 1) Use `$.ajax` with `async: false` option. 2) Use callback pattern 3) Use promise pattern 4) Call `console.log` inside of `$.getJSON()`'s data callback.

Comment: @woozyking - `async:false` is a horrible idea and should never be used.  It's bad in a whole bunch of different ways - not the least of which is that it locks up the browser during the networking.

Comment: @jfriend00 sure, yet it exists as a valid way documented on jQuery official site so I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @woozyking - It is a bad recommendation to even consider it.  It leads to a bad user experience and simply should not be used.  People can write lots of bad code.  That doesn't mean we should mention all the bad ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would suggest you do this using jQuery promises:

```
function getCities(initialUrl) {
    var results = [];

    function nextPage(url) {
        return $.ajax(url, {method: "POST", data: {json: src[cntr++]}}).then(function(data) {
            $.each(data.results, function (k, v) {
                results.push(v.city_name);
            });
            if (data.next) {
                return nextPage(data.next);
            } else {
                return results;
            }
        });
    }

    return nextPage(initialUrl);
}

getCities('http://url.com/api/v1/cities/?page=1').then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
}, function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

This allows you to call then function and then get the data out of the function to use in other code.  It also provides an error handling path.

The getCities function takes the first URL and then returns a promise that resolves with the array of results as it's fulfilled value.

The internal `nextPage()` function takes the next URL.  I tests the url it gets in the results and then either calls itself again on that url chaining the next promise to the original or returns the final result as the ultimate fulfilled value of the promise.

Comment: @sammy88888888 - Please consider learning how to use promises to sequence asynchronous operations and handle and propagate errors.   It's been standardized in ES6 and is the modern way to write async code.  Your approach in your question and the answer you accepted does not allow you to get the data out of your function and it does not do any error handling, both of which come practically for free when properly using promises.

Comment: I attempted to implement your answer but it resulted in only the first page of results being returned. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sammy88888888 - I didn't have the code right, but I've fixed and simplified it now. I built a simulation here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s1hhxztv/ to verify it's all working. This approach gives you a nice clean interface to use for calling it.

Comment: That's really great and a lot cleaner than what I had before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, `console.log` is executed before the requests are completed. Instead you would want to do something like this:

```
var results = [];
function nextPage(url) {
    if (!url) {
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data.results, function (k, v) {
            results.push(v.city_name);
        });
        if(data.next){
            // There is a next page, continue:
            nextPage(data.next);
        }else{
            // You're done:
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
}

nextPage('http://url.com/api/v1/cities/?page=1');
```